# API FaceDetection bounding box is coming back undefined and not displaying the box I've styled

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a face detection application that I am making that uses Clarifai API to detect the face of an image that is input by that images URL. I will post the code in here that shows the FaceRecognition component. as well as the App.js script that pertains to this issue. currently my bounding box information is returning undefined when it should give me a bounding box around the face it detects. that is the best I can really say. Nothing I have done has worked

I have tried console logging the box which returns an object but I am not sure where the box info is at that i need, or for that matter how I would access it. Maybe I am taking the wrong approach on a side note axios.post is coming back as not a function in the model.js script that the API uses, this is a TypeError though.

```
import React from "react";
import './FaceRecognition.css';

const FaceRecognition = ({ imageUrl, box }) => {
    console.log(box);
    return (
        <div className='center ma'>
            <div className='absolute mt2'>
                <img id='inputimage' alt='' src={imageUrl} width='500px' height='auto' />
                <div className='bounding-box' 
                    style={{ top: box.top, right: box.right, left: box.left, bottom: box.bottom }}></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FaceRecognition;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import ParticlesBg from 'particles-bg'
import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import './App.css';

const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '18d772d83bae4ee58c9a4902be5e6d7a'
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      box: {},
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false,
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        entries: 0,
        joined: ''
      }
    }
  }

  loadUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      user: {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        entries: data.entries,
        joined: data.joined
      }
    })
  }


  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const box = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    const newBox = {
      left: box.left_col * width,
      top: box.top_row * height,
      right: width - (box.right_col * width),
      bottom: height - (box.bottom_row * height)
    }
    this.setState({box: newBox})
  };
```

```
onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input });
    app.models.predict('face-detection', this.state.input)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('hi', response)
        if (response) {
          fetch('http://localhost:3001/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              id: this.state.user.id
            })
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
            .then(count => {
              this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count }))
            })

        }
        this.calculateFaceLocation(response)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

```
render() {
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route, box } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ParticlesBg type="cobweb" bg={true} />
        <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        {route === 'home'
          ? <div>
            <Logo />
            <Rank
              name={this.state.user.name}
              entries={this.state.user.entries}
            />
            <ImageLinkForm
              onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
              onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
            />
            <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
          </div>
          : (
            route === 'signin'
              ? <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```